# Initializing LSTM hidden state Tensorflow/Keras

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, lstm

Can someone explain how can I initialize hidden state of LSTM in tensorflow? I am trying to build LSTM recurrent auto-encoder, so after i have that model trained i want to transfer learned hidden state of unsupervised model to hidden state of supervised model.
Is that even possible with current API?
This is paper I am trying to recreate:

http://papers.nips.cc/paper/5949-semi-supervised-sequence-learning.pdf

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes - this is possible but truly cumbersome. Let's go through an example.

1. Defining a model:

   ```
   from keras.layers import LSTM, Input
   from keras.models import Model

   input = Input(batch_shape=(32, 10, 1))
   lstm_layer = LSTM(10, stateful=True)(input)

   model = Model(input, lstm_layer)
   model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mse")
   ```

   It's important to build and compile model first as in compilation the initial states are reset. Moreover - you need to specify a `batch_shape` where `batch_size` is specified as in this scenario our network should be `stateful` (which is done by setting a `stateful=True` mode.
2. Now we could set the values of initial states:

   ```
   import numpy
   import keras.backend as K

   hidden_states = K.variable(value=numpy.random.normal(size=(32, 10)))
   cell_states = K.variable(value=numpy.random.normal(size=(32, 10)))

   model.layers[1].states[0] = hidden_states
   model.layers[1].states[1] = cell_states
   ```

   Note that you need to provide states as a `keras` variables. `states[0]` holds hidden states and `states[1]` holds cell states.

Hope that helps.

Comment: if i want to set just the initial hidden state, would the code be model.layers[1].states[0][0] = h_0

Answer (score 7):

As stated in the Keras API documentation for recurrent layers (https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/):

> **Note on specifying the initial state of RNNs**
>
> You can specify the initial state of RNN layers symbolically by calling them with the keyword argument `initial_state`. The value of `initial_state` should be a tensor or list of tensors representing the initial state of the RNN layer.
>
> You can specify the initial state of RNN layers numerically by calling `reset_states` with the keyword argument `states`. The value of `states` should be a numpy array or list of numpy arrays representing the initial state of the RNN layer.

Since the LSTM layer has two states (hidden state and cell state) the value of `initial_state` and `states` is a list of two tensors.

---

### Examples

#### Stateless LSTM

Input shape: (batch, timesteps, features) = (1, 10, 1)
Number of units in the LSTM layer = 8 (i.e. dimensionality of hidden and cell state)

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

inputs = np.random.random([1, 10, 1]).astype(np.float32)

lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(8)

c_0 = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.random([1, 8]).astype(np.float32))
h_0 = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.random([1, 8]).astype(np.float32))

outputs = lstm(inputs, initial_state=[h_0, c_0])
```

#### Stateful LSTM

Input shape: (batch, timesteps, features) = (1, 10, 1)
Number of units in the LSTM layer = 8 (i.e. dimensionality of hidden and cell state)

Note that for stateful lstm you need to specify also `batch_size`.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from pprint import pprint

inputs = np.random.random([1, 10, 1]).astype(np.float32)

lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(8, stateful=True, batch_size=(1, 10, 1))

c_0 = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.random([1, 8]).astype(np.float32))
h_0 = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.random([1, 8]).astype(np.float32))

outputs = lstm(inputs, initial_state=[h_0, c_0])
```

With a Stateful LSTM, the states are not reset at the end of each sequence and we can notice that the output of the layer correspond to the hidden state (i.e. `lstm.states[0]`) at the last timestep:

```
>>> pprint(outputs)
<tf.Tensor: id=821, shape=(1, 8), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 0.07119043,  0.07012419, -0.06118739, -0.11008392,  0.00573938,
        -0.05663438,  0.11196419,  0.02663924]], dtype=float32)>
>>>
>>> pprint(lstm.states)
[<tf.Variable 'lstm_1/Variable:0' shape=(1, 8) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 0.07119043,  0.07012419, -0.06118739, -0.11008392,  0.00573938,
        -0.05663438,  0.11196419,  0.02663924]], dtype=float32)>,
 <tf.Variable 'lstm_1/Variable:0' shape=(1, 8) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 0.14726108,  0.13584498, -0.12986949, -0.22309153,  0.0125412 ,
        -0.11446435,  0.22290672,  0.05397629]], dtype=float32)>]
```

Calling `reset_states()` it is possible to reset the states:

```
>>> lstm.reset_states()
>>> pprint(lstm.states)
[<tf.Variable 'lstm_1/Variable:0' shape=(1, 8) dtype=float32, numpy=array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)>,
 <tf.Variable 'lstm_1/Variable:0' shape=(1, 8) dtype=float32, numpy=array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)>]
>>>
```

or to set them to a specific value:

```
>>> lstm.reset_states(states=[h_0, c_0])
>>> pprint(lstm.states)
[<tf.Variable 'lstm_1/Variable:0' shape=(1, 8) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0.59103394, 0.68249655, 0.04518601, 0.7800545 , 0.3799634 ,
        0.27347744, 0.54415804, 0.9889024 ]], dtype=float32)>,
 <tf.Variable 'lstm_1/Variable:0' shape=(1, 8) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0.43390197, 0.28252542, 0.27139077, 0.19655049, 0.7568088 ,
        0.05909375, 0.68569875, 0.19087408]], dtype=float32)>]
>>>
>>> pprint(h_0)
<tf.Tensor: id=422, shape=(1, 8), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0.59103394, 0.68249655, 0.04518601, 0.7800545 , 0.3799634 ,
        0.27347744, 0.54415804, 0.9889024 ]], dtype=float32)>
>>>
>>> pprint(c_0)
<tf.Tensor: id=421, shape=(1, 8), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0.43390197, 0.28252542, 0.27139077, 0.19655049, 0.7568088 ,
        0.05909375, 0.68569875, 0.19087408]], dtype=float32)>
>>>
```

Comment: When doing this I get an error saying that the hidden states need to be symbolic. I am using the functional API. How can I convert the initial state to symbolic?

Answer (score 3):

I used this approach, totally worked out for me:

```
lstm_cell = LSTM(cell_num, return_state=True) 

output, h, c = lstm_cell(input, initial_state=[h_prev, c_prev])
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming an RNN is in layer 1 and hidden/cell states are numpy arrays.  You can do this:

```
from keras import backend as K

K.set_value(model.layers[1].states[0], hidden_states)
K.set_value(model.layers[1].states[1], cell_states)
```

States can also be set using

```
model.layers[1].states[0] = hidden_states
model.layers[1].states[1] = cell_states
```

but when I did it this way my state values stayed constant even after stepping the RNN.